# Sending serial commands to a Kangaroo motion controller with pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

**Hi everybody**, I need help with following problem please:

I try to drive a [Dimension Engineering Kangaroo/Sabertooth](https://www.dimensionengineering.com/products/kangaroo) motor controller from a Python script using [pyserial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/).

Everything works so far except that the motor output stops after some time and the USB/serial connection becomes 'unresponsive'. The faster the rate at which the serial commands are sent, the quicker this happens.

This is how I initialize the serial connection:

```
# open serial port
Saber = serial.Serial("COM1", 19200, timeout=1, write_timeout=0)

# starting the motor
Saber.write("1,start\r".encode("gbk"))
```

Then the position commands are sent using a loop:

```
while True:
    pos = 2000  # just an example, the script calculates a new required position every iteration
    command = "1,p" + str(pos) + "s500\r"
    Saber.write(command.encode("gbk"))
    time.sleep(.1)  # the lower this break, the faster the device becomes unresponsive...?
```

After the device stops, I have to disconnect it / power it down, to be able to open a serial connection again.

Could it be that some sort of buffer gets filled and 'locks' the port?
I have tried to free the read/write buffers using:

```
Saber.reset_input_buffer()
Saber.reset_output_buffer()
```

But that does not solve the problem :/ **Any help is greatly apprechiated! Thanks!**

Comment: Mmm, have you tried checking and printing how many bytes are written each time? `bytesWritten = Saber.write(...)` You might see that the last write is incomplete or somesuch if a buffer is getting full. You might also try seeing if there is data available for you to read after each write, in case some buffer of error messages from the 'roo is getting full. Just guessing.